# How does the authentication process with the salted hash in shadow work

Tags: authentication, ldap, shadow, cryptography

Does the supplied password during login get converted to a salted hash and then compared to the one in /etc/shadow?  /what if the user is in LDAP but not in the shadow file?  Would it use kerberos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For salt, the idea is simple:

3DES for example has 11 characters of hashed password plus 2 characters of salt. Lets say the outcome is: SSHHHHHHHHHHH. That's what's stored in the shadow file. I.e. both the salt and the hash.

Once I type my password, the library gets the shadow entry, extracts the salt (first two characters), combines the salt with my unencrypted password (the one I just typed) and generates a new hash. If the new hash is the same as the one in the shadow file then it means that my password matches the original one.

The idea is the same behind all cases of salted hashes. The format in the shadow file has changed a bit to be easier to distinguish between different hash algorithms but eventually all that is stored are: (optionally) an id that identifies the hashing function, the salt and the hash. Then using any inputed password, the system generates a new hash (by applying the hashing function to the salt+password) and compares that with the stored one.

For LDAP I believe that this is the same. I.e. the system fetches the entry from LDAP and performs the same set of functions.